# Trying to center my tabs in my navigation bar to the length of the page HTML

Tags: html, css

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccfff5;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="about us"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li class="location"><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
    <li class="facts"><a href="facts.html">Nutritional Facts</a></li>
    <li class="promo"><a href="promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
</ul>
```

All of my navigation tags are to the left and not proportioned to the page size. When I change the alignment it does not change with the size of the page. What am I doing wrong?

This is what my navigation bar currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including `ul.topnav li { float: left; }` pushes all `li` to the left.

Removing it and adding a `text-align: center` to `ul.topnav` should give you what you want.

[Here's a JSFiddle showing that.](https://jsfiddle.net/Quillot/vth4hs59/) Feel free experiment with it to see how `float: left` affects the html, etc.